# Binding inside ListBox, need to update

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I use Listbox in my application.

```
<ListBox Name="lbMain">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <Expander Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource convCaption}, 
          Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsExpanded="True">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text={Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay,
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}>
          </TextBlock> 
           <TextBlock Text={Binding SecondName, Mode=TwoWay,   pdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}>
          </TextBlock> 
        </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
   MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
   lbMain.ItemSource = myModel;
}
```

This is model

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string FirstName{get; set; }
   public string SecondName{get; set; }
}
```

This is converter (convCaption)

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter ...)
  {
     MyModel model =(MyModel)value;
     return string.Format("This is {0}, {1}", Model.FirstName, ModelSecondName)
  }
```

It all works. But when I change FirstName or SecondName I need to change Header in Expander. If I write {Mode = TwoWay} show error - "need path". I like to write correctly binding for Expander(to headline the updated)?

Comment: You should try binding correctly first (preferably in xaml)... And you only need to change the properties and raise(implement) PropertyChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `MyModel` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` event each time `FirstName` or `SecondName` has changed, like so:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (_firstName == value) return;
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string _secondName;

    public string SecondName
    {
        get { return _secondName; }
        set
        {
            if (_secondName == value) return;
            _secondName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SecondName");
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use `MultiBinding` with `StringFormat` like so:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}This is {0} {1}">
                    <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                    <Binding Path="SecondName"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `MyModel` class. Please see the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) page on MSDN for help. Also, you don't really need a `Converter` to join the two names... there's a much simpler way... just override the `ToString()` method in that class too:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("This is {0}, {1}", FirstName, SecondName);
}
```

Comment: instead of having to override `ToString()`, you can also just use a `StringFormat` and keep it in xaml with a `MultiBinding` to the two parts of the name.

Comment: Dude, no one *has* to override `ToString`, but that's definitely less code than that of a `MultiBinding`. I know which I'd prefer to use. :)

Comment: Thank you, but I was not comfortable to use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: If you don't want to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, then you can forget about using WPF... it is *not* really optional.

Comment: Yeah it is, you can use dps for pretty much everything... Though I wouldn't recommend it. And how is it less code, exactly?

Comment: @StefanDenchev, that is *exactly* why I added the word 'really' in 'not really optional'... I knew someone would say something like that. However, is implementing all `DependencyProperty` properties easier than implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Not in my opinion.

Comment: Well, that sort of makes it optional as in you *can* opt for it if you say totally hate inpcs :P(just how you can opt for GIMP even though Photoshop is so much better, but i digress)... Though i guess it's not all that relevant... Nice answer overall.